# Hide pick list field only on record creation using Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, picklist

How to hide a custom pick list field only on record creation on 'Opportunity' using Visualforce, and the same pick list field should be visible/editable on edit/view of the same record?

Comment: Can you please post the code which you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar Question in this SFSE [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162924/how-do-we-detect-if-visualforce-page-is-being-rendered-on-a-page-layout-from-its). The basic idea is to parse the URL parameters to know about the VF page mode. Once you get to know the mode, you can conditionally render the picklist based on that.

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="CheckState" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Industry}" rendered="{!IF(vfMode != 'New','true','false')}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```